# How to accelerate the following function in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, normalization

I have a complex function which takes forever to run on large pandas dataframe and I do not find ways to accelerate it. Do you guys have any tip?
I have used `numba`, but this is clearly not enough. I have also tried to used index reference to exploit pandas capacity to the maximum but, I am sure there are other ways I have not implemented.

What this function does, is basically takes a dataframe with random time spaced events and normalize it into second spaced events. There are three different types of events (`TRADE`, `BEST_BID`, `BEST_ASK`), so for each second I should have three lines (one of each event). If not event of a specific type happened during that second, we reuse previous value.

Thank you for your help!

```
@numba.jit
def convertTicksToSeconds(dataFrame_df):    
    idxs = dataFrame_df['data_all'][dataFrame_df['data_all']['time_change']].index.tolist()
    previous_idx = 0
    progress_i = 0
    #Creation of the df to holfd the normalized data
    normalized_Data = pandas.DataFrame( columns=['timestamp', 'B.A.T', 'price', 'volume', 'asset'])
    BAT_type =['TRADE','BEST_BID','BEST_ASK']
    tmp_time = dataFrame_df['data_all']['timestamp'][0]
    data_TRADE = {'timestamp': tmp_time, 'B.A.T': 'TRADE', 'price': 0, 'volume': 0, 'asset': dataFrame_df['data_all']['asset'][0]}
    data_BID = {'timestamp': tmp_time, 'B.A.T': 'BEST_BID', 'price': 0, 'volume': 0, 'asset': dataFrame_df['data_all']['asset'][0]}
    data_ASK = {'timestamp': tmp_time, 'B.A.T': 'BEST_ASK', 'price': 0, 'volume': 0, 'asset': dataFrame_df['data_all']['asset'][0]}
    for BAT in BAT_type:
        for idx in idxs:
            if dataFrame_df['data_all'][previous_idx:idx-1][dataFrame_df['data_all']['B.A.T'] == BAT].empty == False:
                timestamp = dataFrame_df['data_all']['timestamp'][idx]
                price = dataFrame_df['data_all']['price'][previous_idx:idx-1][dataFrame_df['data_all']['B.A.T'] == BAT]
                volume = dataFrame_df['data_all']['volume'][previous_idx:idx-1][dataFrame_df['data_all']['B.A.T'] == BAT]
                total_volume = volume.sum()
                weighted_price = price * volume
                weighted_price = weighted_price.sum() / total_volume
                volume = volume.mean()
                asset = dataFrame_df['data_all']['asset'][idx]

                if BAT == 'TRADE':
                    data_TRADE = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'B.A.T': BAT, 'price': weighted_price, 'volume': volume, 'asset': asset}

                elif BAT == 'BEST_BID':
                    data_BID = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'B.A.T': BAT, 'price': weighted_price, 'volume': volume, 'asset': asset}

                elif BAT == 'BEST_ASK':
                    data_ASK = {'timestamp': timestamp, 'B.A.T': BAT, 'price': weighted_price, 'volume': volume, 'asset': asset}

                print data_TRADE
                print data_BID
                print data_ASK
                normalized_Data.append(data_TRADE, ignore_index=True)
                normalized_Data.append(data_BID, ignore_index=True)
                normalized_Data.append(data_ASK, ignore_index=True)
                previous_idx = idx
                progress_i += 1
                tmp = (progress_i / len(idxs))*100
                print ('Progress : ' + str(tmp) + ' %')
    return normalized_Data
```

Comment: Pandas has several methods of resampling and reindexing, and you can reindex on 1 second (or any time interval). I can't point you to the relevant documentation right now, but I know it's there somewhere.

Comment: @DainDwarf Yes, but the problem is not simply re-indexing. It is also averaging on the information present in the said one second. Otherwise I lose valuable information.

Comment: Can't you average with a groupby? Something like `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1S')).mean().fillna(0)` ?

Comment: @DainDwarf Hey buddy, I found a way. Your answer was not the one, but it helped in showing the right path. I basically used the following method: `TRADE_PRICEVOL_SERIES.resample('1S').sum()`  Using this I created  two series and used them to calculate my VWAP on one second. It is super duper much faster. Cheers!